# Function to create a new variable not working in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I am creating a function to help me quickly recode variables into numerical values, as a form of practice. The idea behind creating the function is to quickly recode several values into numerical form, for any length. If a dataset is really long for instance, the function in theory should recode all of these values without having to manually type out each condition in which to recode it into a specific value.

For instance:

```
levels(d$letters)

[1] a b c d
```

The general form of the function is to:

```
d$letters.recode[d$letters == "a"] <- 1
d$letters.recode[d$letters == "b"] <- 2
d$letters.recode[d$letters == "c"] <- 3
```

And using this function:

```
 rc.f <- function(a, b){
   x <- levels(a) 
   y <- length(a)
   b <- NA
   for (i in 1:y){
      z <- b[a==x[i]] <- i
  } 
}
```

In theory, the idea is that this function should create another variable, where a is recoded as 1, b is recoded as 2 and so on.

However when I run `rc.f(d$letters, d$letters.recode)`, no new variables are created in the dataset, and the function does not return an error.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Another example dataset `d`:

Say for a list of respondents they are assigned a category depending on their region:

```
 Respondent   Region        
     1           d
     2           b
     3           g
     4           c 
     5           e
     6           c
     7           f
     8           a
```

I am looking for a way to recode `d$Region` into a numerical value, to `d$Region.R`.

Using the same function as above, I am wondering whether I can use the function to create another variable in the dataframe, by inputting `d$Region` and `d$Region.R` into the function. So recoding a,b,c,[...],g into 1,2,3,[...],7.

Comment: "[...] _where a is recoded as 1, and b is recoded as 2._" What about `c` and `d`? Shall these become `3` and `4`? Can you update with expected output?

Comment: Done. Is it a problem trying to create a new variable inside of a function?

Comment: What is `b <- NA` good for? Later you try to extract elements from `b`. Also, what should be the desired output if the input was `x`, `y` and `z`.

Comment: `b <- NA` was testing to see if that would be the problem. I was looking to create a variable with all NA values, to see if that would fix the problem. The X and Y variables were just placeholders to save the values from the length and levels functions.

Comment: I am still not entirely sure about what you are trying to achieve. Can you update with another example input and desired output?

Comment: Does the new example help?

Comment: What is the purpose of `b` as an argument to your function?

Comment: Thanks, that's better. Do you need `d$Region.R <- match(d$Region, letters)` ?

Comment: What does the match function do?

Comment: Maybe what you are after is something like this `d$Region.R <- factor(d$Region, 
                     levels = c("a", "b", "c"),
                     labels = 1:3); df.Region.R <- as.numeric(df$Region.R)` if you really want them to be numeric

Comment: @jdobres the purpose of the b argument is to create argument b as another variable in the dataset.

Comment: @Suren The idea behind creating the function is so that it could be applied to any data for a variable, of any length. So while that works in general, it could be really tedious for a long dataset.

Comment: If you coerce factor into numeric, it will turn factor levels to integers. Your only task then is to get levels in the correct order and presto!

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to a,b,f,d as 1,2,4,3 then use following**

I have updated your code for function rc.f a little bit

- Removed second argument b, since we are giving b <- NA ,so we do not need second argument
- We do not need other variable to store the value of b , so i removed z
- Since every argument is not factor so we need to coerce it into factor
- we do not need y , we can directly put length(a) in for loop condition
- and last but not the least the last line is the output of the function unless we use return, so there i putted b in last

The code is

```
rc.f <- function(a)
{
 a<-as.factor(a)
 x <- levels(a) 
 b <- NA
 for (i in 1:length(a))
  {
    b[a==x[i]] <- i
  }
 b
}
```

let us take an example

```
> l<-c("a","b","b","a","a","g","h","y","f","v","h","j","f","d","a","s","s","s")
> l
[1] "a" "b" "b" "a" "a" "g" "h" "y" "f" "v" "h" "j" "f"
[14] "d" "a" "s" "s" "s"
> rc.f(l)
[1]  1  2  2  1  1  5  6 10  4  9  6  7  4  3  1  8  8  8
```

**If you want a,b,f,d as 1,2,6,4 then use following**

```
rc.f <- function(a)
{
  a<-as.factor(a)
  b <- NA
  for (i in 1:26)
  {
    b[a==letters[i]] <- i
  }
  b
}
```

lets take an example

```
> l<-c("a","b","b","a","a","g","h","y","f","v","h","j","f","d","a","s","s","s")
> l
[1] "a" "b" "b" "a" "a" "g" "h" "y" "f" "v" "h" "j" "f" "d"
[15] "a" "s" "s" "s"
> rc.f(l)
[1]  1  2  2  1  1  7  8 25  6 22  8 10  6  4  1 19 19 19
```